# I'm trying to change placeholder in WordPress theme, but I can't find where it's existing

Tags: php, html, wordpress

I use a WordPress Woo-commerce template called "KuteShop", and I am trying to change the Placeholder Text "I'm searching for..." and "All Cate." as in the picture below:

[image]

but I can't do that, I searched everywhere, NOT in the Advanced editor, NOT in the Theme Options, NOT in the WordPress Settings, Nor in any place.

How can I modify it?

Comment: You can find this two ways, export you entire WordPress database into .sql file and search for those two strings.  Other way is to download your entire wp-contents directory and search the files (using something like Notepad++) to find the strings in the body of the files.  These simply may not be built to be easily changed.

Comment: If you want to do this in your functions.php file, here is the documentation: https://docs.woocommerce.com/document/overriding-the-product-search-box-widget/

Comment: THX, I will try.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The process is really simple, KuteShop include a language file: "languages/kuteshop.pot"

You simply should open this file with the PoEdit application (that is distributed for free: https://poedit.net/), and create the language file for your website's language, entering a hypothetical translation of this text with the text you want to display on your website.